# MediaPlayer life cycle

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Will `onCompletion` will be called every time after an error?
According to the documentation it's not supposed to be that way, but I've noticed it's happening, I've noticed that `onCompletion` is called after `onError`, the question is can I count on it to happen every time, and how can I know that the player reached `onCompletion` due to error?

Thanks

Comment: Hi i just visited

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

and seen lines that

If the looping mode was set to false , the player engine calls a user supplied callback method, `OnCompletion.onCompletion()`, if a `OnCompletionListener` is registered beforehand via `setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener)`. The invoke of the callback signals that the object is now in the PlaybackCompleted state.

is it the case what happened in yours approach, please investigate.

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay the question is whether it'll be always called after an error? and how can I know if it was called with error or not?

Comment: I've found the answer it's in the return of the `onError` method

Comment: look at mediaplayer lifecycle http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif